# How do I configure my broadband connection?

Tags: internet, 9.10, broadband

I have broadband connection,in windows it is working properly.In ubuntu 9.10 it is not working,So suggest me possible solution..

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer supported. You should consider upgrading to a new release.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about 3g/4g mobile broadband like an aircard install the "usb_mode_switch"..so you would need to be connected to the internet to be able to install it.what type of card are you using?

Comment: I will not flag this to become a comment, but in future, ask questions in comments, and leave answers as answers ;).